# insert new row if not exist and get new or existing id

Tags: php, mysql, insert, not-exists, last-insert-id

I want to do the following by using **NOT EXISTS** and **last_insert_id()** by one code.
below code satisfies my needs, Col1 is a unique key there for **code will not insert data if it already exists**. If a new row is inserted or is already exist always **code return the $id** of relevant row.

```
<?php 
mysql_query(" INSERT table SET col1='data1', col2='data2' ");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE col1='data1' ") ;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) { $id=$row['id'];}

header("Location:page.php?id=$id"); 
?>
```

Comment: so what is your question if it satisfies your needs?

Comment: @altafhussain I want to do the same by using NOT EXISTS and last_insert_id() by one code to increase the performance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting last inserted UniqueId from MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106538/getting-last-inserted-uniqueid-from-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Let me put my thoughts here. I don't know whether i quite understood the problem.

**ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**

```
INSERT INTO table (ID, Col1, Col2)
   VALUES (100, value1, value2)
       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ID = 100; -- or whatever you need

INSERT INTO table (ID, Col1, Col2)
   VALUES (100, value1, value2)
       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ID = ID; -- this keeps the ID to what ever it was, no change.
```

**NOT EXISTS**

```
INSERT INTO funds (ID, Col1, Col2)
    SELECT 100, "value1", "value2"
    FROM dual
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
          FROM table 
          WHERE ID = 100
    );
```

"You can specify `DUAL` as a dummy table name in situations 
                                           where no tables are referenced:

**Additional thoughts.**

**REPLACE INTO**

This works exactly like `INSERT` with one important exception. If a `duplicate row` is found, it deletes it first and then performs the `INSERT`, so we get no error messages.

```
<?php 
   mysql_query(" REPLACE INTO table SET col1='data1', col2='data2' ");
```

**INSERT IGNORE**

This is a way to suppress the `duplicate errors`, usually to prevent the application from breaking. Sometimes you may want to attempt to insert a new row and just let it fail without any complaints in case there is a duplicate found.

```
<?php 
   mysql_query(" INSERT IGNORE INTO table SET col1='data1', col2='data2' ");
```